# What is this bug? And should I be concerned?

Tags: pest-control, insect

I live in a high-rise condo. I have noticed a few bugs flying or crawling around in the room lately. They look harmless, but I am not sure where they come from. They have a unique trapezoid shape. Apologies for the poor picture quality. I tried. What is this bug and should I be concerned?
[image]

Comment: Are you  in Australia?

Comment: @Harper Nope. U.S. East Coast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kudzu beetle. Invasive species from Asia.

Comment: Seems to be spot on.

Answer (score 1):

I vote [stink bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug). They like to come inside in the winter, and it seems like the population or territory has expanded recently.  I'd never seen them till a few years ago, now they're all over in the fall.  (Central NYS)

Comment: That actually crossed my mind. But I have also see stink bugs near my windows. And they are much bigger with long legs. The ones bugging me in the room are smaller and all black. Maybe they are a different strain? I don't know.

Comment: Stink bugs tend to be more pointed and are also clumsy insects.  They're colorful because it's nature's way of saying you don't want to eat me.  This looks more like a beetle.